# Set multi colour on text of button control

Tags: c#, winforms, button

I am working on a c# accounting project where I need to have multi colour button in which a alphabet is coloured differently (which signifies that alphabet key has been assigned as the shortcut key to that button ) from the rest of the text  so that it's easy for the user to recognize which key has been assign for a particular button . I have searched everywhere on the internet but don't find any answer . I also request not to mind my bad english  writing as I am not good in it . I am attaching a gif for reference .

Comment: This is not possible with a standard Winforms button.  And I have never seen any custom control that can do this.

Comment: You can't do this using the built in controls in winforms, but you can inherit a button and override it's paint method to do it. It's not going to be very simple, though.

Comment: I know that it's very difficult . Can u please share the link for how to override the paint method to achieve the same .

Comment: There are so many exmaples of overriding Paint and doing a 'ower-drawing' that you will find one easily. But if the text is static an image will be easier, imo.

Comment: The text is static but it will change its colour once it gets focus

Comment: See [Draw text in random colors in C#](http://csharphelper.com/blog/2014/08/draw-text-in-random-colors-in-c/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use WPF project for this problem.

```
<Button >
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Label Margin="0" Padding="0" >Click </Label>
    <Label Foreground="DarkRed" Margin="0" Padding="0" > M</Label>
    <Label Margin="0" Padding="0" >e</Label>
  </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Comment: I can not use wpf as desktop windows project is the only option for me as of now .

Comment: Then you can use BackgroundImage properties. You have to create an image same size as your button. (You can use PNG format).